# JWT replay validation based on jti claim rather than on expiration time

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

In my Asp.net Core based Web API I would like to use `jti` (JWT ID) claim to prevent replay attacks while working with JWT (JSON Web Tokens).

As suggested I configured JWT Bearer authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateTokenReplay = true,
        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) =>
        {
            // Resolving decryption key
        },
        TokenReplayValidator = (expirationTime, /*string*/ token, validationParameters) =>
        {
            // I can check expiration time, but there is no way to check jti
        },
    };
    o.SaveToken = true;
});
```

In replay validator I can access an expiration time, but there is no way to get `jti` somehow.

I find it a bit confusing. What common might have a replay attack and an expiration time?

Moreover we have another validator:

```
bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, 
                       SecurityToken securityToken, 
                       TokenValidationParameters validationParameters);
```

Here I can access the `SecurityToken` data including `jti`, but I can't believe that this is a right place for `jti`-based replay attack validation.

So the question is: how could I get `SecurityToken` data inside `TokenReplayValidator`?

**UPDATE:**

After the @orhtej2 comment, I checked the possibility which he suggested. That works indeed:

```
TokenReplayValidator = (expirationTime, token, validationParameters) =>
{
    var handler = o.SecurityTokenValidators.OfType<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>().First();
    var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    var jti = securityToken.Id;
    // check replay attack
},
```

Well, it is a solution, but requires additional token parsing (which cannot be good - unnecessary calculations required on the each HTTP call).

I would like to keep the question unanswered until some better solution found.

Comment: Perhaps simple call to [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451144(v=vs.114).aspx) on provided stringified token will do the trick?

Comment: You have an excellent point regarding this interface. It's really the ID of the token that matters and not the raw text of it, especially for other types such as SAML.

Comment: but the expiration time **is** relevant, because your replay cache can safely purge items older than the expiry since the normal token validation will not allow an expired one to be used